# Displaying a div on a image with hover function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to make a image gallery on the image it will show a div on the image when you hover or mouseover and I am using fade in/out functions on the hover function.
The problem is that it keeps fading in and out automatically when I hover the image.

I have this block of code for the hover fade in/out:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {

    $(".hover-box").fadeIn({
        duration: 1000
    });

}, function() {

    $(".hover-box").fadeOut({
        duration: 1000
    });
});
```

I am trying to solve what I can do so it only fade in when I mouseover the image and then fade out when the mouse is leaving the image. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Could you post a fiddle of illustrating the issue? or some additional code so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: i sure can but i want u to know that it will hover the my problem is that when i mouseover then the div i want to fade in and out it it automatically just fade in and out when i mouseover the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hide the .hover-box when you leave the .hover-box not the image.

```
$("#back").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#front").fadeIn(1000); 
});

$("#front").mouseleave(function() {
 $("#front").fadeOut(1000);   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4uTM/

Comment: Yes it does fade out because the mouse left the .image bacause the .hover-box overlaps it. #back is your .image , #front is your .hover-box, .image loses the focus, and .hover-box gets the new focus because it is over it. Good luck.

Comment: done sry mate :) im pretty new at this hehe but thanks for the help :) appreciate it :)